# Blender with matlab integration

Tags: matlab, python-2.7, animation, blender

I established a connection between Matlab and blender using MATLAB UDP Simulink block. When I am trying to send values from Matlab to blender via UDP, values coming from Matlab is not completely reflecting in the blender animation, only first only is updating in blender animation.

How to continuously update values from Matlab UDP Simulink in blender.

Comment: Can you share the script you are running in blender? Are you getting any error messages in the console? What version of blender?